# "EOL while scanning single-quoted string"? (backslash in string)

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import os
xp1 = "\Documents and Settings\"
xp2 = os.getenv("USERNAME")
print xp1+xp2
```

Gives me error

```
 File "1.py", line 2 
xp1 = "\Documents and Settings\"
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scannning single-quoted string
```

Can you help me please, do you see the problem?

Comment: Also note how Stack Overflow automatically colors your code so that the problem becomes obvious.

Answer (score 23):

The backslash character is interpreted as an escape. Use double backslashes for windows paths:

```
>>> xp1 = "\\Documents and Settings\\"
>>> xp1
'\\Documents and Settings\\'
>>> print xp1
\Documents and Settings\
>>>
```

Answer (score 11):

Additionally to the blackslash problem, don't join paths with the "+" operator -- use `os.path.join` instead.

Also, construct the path to a user's home directory like that is likely to fail on new versions of Windows. There are API functions for that in pywin32.

Comment: +1 os.path.join is the way to go. Would os.getenv('HOME') be set on Win32? I don't have an MS box to check..

Comment: My poor little XP-in-a-VM has the "USERPROFILE" environment variable, which points to the home directory, but I don't know how official it is.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `os.path.expanduser` function to get the path to a users home-directory. It doesn't even have to be an existing user.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.expanduser('~foo')
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\foo'
>>> print os.path.expanduser('~foo')
C:\Documents and Settings\foo
>>> print os.path.expanduser('~')
C:\Documents and Settings\MizardX
```

"`~user`" is expanded to the path to *user*'s home directory. Just a single "`~`" gets expanded to the current users home directory.

Comment: +1, works correctly on Windows 7, where it is `C:\Users\foo` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Python, as many other languages, uses the backslash as an escape character (the double-quotes at the end of your xp1=... line are therefore considered as part of the string, not as the delimiter of the string).

This is actually pretty basic stuff, so I strongly recommend you read the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) before going any further.

You might be interested in *raw* strings, which do *not* escape backslashes.  Just add *r* just before the string:

```
xp1 = r"\Documents and Settings\"
```

Moreover, when manipulating file paths, you should use the *os.path* module, which will use "/" or "\" depending on the O.S. on which the program is run.  For example:

```
import os.path
xp1 = os.path.join("data","cities","geo.txt")
```

will produce "data/cities/geo.txt" on Linux and "data\cities\geo.txt" on Windows.

Comment: A raw string can't end in an odd number of backslashes.  Try it.

Answer (score 5):

`\"` is interpreted as "insert a double-quote into the string, so you are missing a terminating quote for the string literal.  Note that a raw string `r"\"` can't help either.

Quote from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (bold is mine):

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal r"\n" consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase 'n'. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a valid string literal (**even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes**). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

The answer @MizardX gave is the right way to code what you are doing, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I solved it reading the comment of @Mark Tolonen

This is a wrong path string:

```
xp1 = "\Documents and Settings\"
```

This is a right path string, without the last back slash:

```
xp1 = "\Documents and Settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows

```
for file in glob.glob('C:\Users\7000020370\3D Objects\audio\data\*\*'):
    print(file.split("\\")[0])
```

This will throw error , but the below one will not

```
for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\7000020370\3D Objects\audio\data\*\*'):
    print(file.split("\\")[0])
```