# mixed slashes with os.path.join on windows

Tags: python, windows, path

I tend to use only forward slashes for paths ('/') and python is happy with it also on windows.

In the description of `os.path.join` it says that is the correct way if you want to go cross-platform. But when I use it I get mixed slashes:

```
import os

a = 'c:/'
b = 'myFirstDirectory/'
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'


print os.path.join(a, b, c, d, e)

# Result:
c:/myFirstDirectory/mySecondDirectory\myThirdDirectory\myExecutable.exe
```

Is this correct? Should I check and correct it afterward or there is a better way?

Thanks

EDIT:
I also get mixed slashes when asking for paths

```
import sys
for item in sys.path:
    print item
    
# Result:
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013.5\bin
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013.5\mentalray\scripts\AETemplates
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013.5\Python
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013.5\Python\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013.5\bin\python26.zip\lib-tk
C:/Users/nookie/Documents/maya/2013.5-x64/prefs/scripts
C:/Users/nookie/Documents/maya/2013.5-x64/scripts
C:/Users/nookie/Documents/maya/scripts
C:\Program Files\Nuke7.0v4\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\Nuke7.0v4/plugins/modules
```

Comment: `os` is clever and works out which slashes you need for your OS.  To use it correctly, don't put slashes in your strings a,b,c,d and e - os will add them.

Comment: I see, but what if I get mixed slashes when asking for a path? (I have updated the first post with an example)

Comment: you can use `os.path.normpath(mixed_slashes_path)` and get the slashes normalized. Oh and I'm guessing you're doing this inside of Maya; it does things very much UNIX-like, hence the slashes in there in the paths that it's adding for you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are now providing some of the slashes yourself and letting [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) pick others. It's better to let python pick all of them or provide them all yourself. Python uses backslashes for the latter part of the path, because backslashes are the default on Windows.

```
import os

a = 'c:' # removed slash
b = 'myFirstDirectory' # removed slash
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'

print os.path.join(a + os.sep, b, c, d, e)
```

I haven't tested this, but I hope this helps.  It's more common to have a base path and only having to join one other element, mostly files.

By the way; you can use [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) for those moments you want to have the best separator for the operating system python is running on.

**Edit:** as dash-tom-bang states, apparently for Windows you do need to include a separator for the root of the path. Otherwise you create a relative path instead of an absolute one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what if I get slashes in one string (when having two or more folders)? I have updated the first post with some paths I get from sys.path

Comment: It depends on where that path is coming from. But most of the time, you should already have those slashes in the correct format. That is, if you get the path through Python.

If you have some external source you do not control and that source provides forward slashes instead of backward slashes; you might want to fix that up first.

Comment: So I should check the string afterwards and make sure that the format is correct?

Comment: No I would check your external input (the input you apparently do not control the format of) **before** putting it in `os.path.join`. This way you make sure that `os.path.join` does not make bad decisions based on possibly bad input.

Comment: I don't see the danger of having bad input here, in the sense of "bad" meaning "having mixed separators". IMO Windows allows happily for mixing `/` and ``\``, so no problem here.

Comment: No real danger but if you want your code to be cross-platform (as he is suggesting), it's better to program on the defensive side and sanitize your input beforehand. Although that could be classified as an opinion rather than a fact, of course ;)

Comment: Splitting out the root directory and re-joining will not yield the correct result; the root of `C:` needs to be specified. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/.

Comment: Thanks @dash-tom-bang, I updated the answer accordingly. Strange that nobody has noticed this before, could it be version related or something?

Comment: There is no need to remove slashes. **Just use the standard `os.path.normpath()` function** to normalise paths if you are worried about mixed slashes in paths. There is no need to avoid them anyway, as Windows is happy to accept paths with mixed slashes.

Comment: My issue, is the os.getcwd() conflicts, so there has to be a reason behind that convention of best choice that join() makes, but getcwd() does not have a alternative. try: import posixpath ; print(posixpath.join(*os.getcwd().split('\\'))) # may work for some of us?

Comment: `as dash-tom-bang states, apparently for Windows you do need to include a separator`: this is done with your `os.sep` I think.

Answer (score 73):

You can use `.replace()` after `path.join()` to ensure the slashes are correct:

```
# .replace() all backslashes with forwardslashes
print os.path.join(a, b, c, d, e).replace("\\","/")
```

This gives the output:

```
c:/myFirstDirectory/mySecondDirectory/myThirdDirectory/myExecutable.exe
```

As @sharpcloud suggested, it would be better to remove the slashes from your input strings, however this is an alternative.

Comment: Would it be better to just import posixpath instead of os.path and then do `posixpath.join(a, b, c, d, e)` which will always give you forward slashes.

Comment: @semicolon, isn't posixpath the same as importing os.path? In any case, on my windows machine `posixpath.join()` still returns mixed slashes.

Comment: If you look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), os.path will import one of posixpath, ntpath, macpath or os2emxpath based on your os. I am surprised you still get mixed slashes with posixpath. I just tested it on a windows machine and `os.path.join('foo', 'bar')` gave me `'a\\b'` and `posixpath.join('foo', 'bar')` gave me `'a/b'`.

Comment: I should have clarified that `os.path.join()` (and the module it imports) does not replace slashes within the strings it is joining, which may lead to mixed slashes (as is happening in the question).

Comment: That is true, but it seemed as though the only existing slashes within the strings it was joining were forward slashes, and as posixpath also uses forward slashes you would not get any mixed slashes using posixpath in the OP's scenario.

Comment: Even preferable I would say would be to use `os.abspath()` to normalize all sorts of things. Perhaps there's something in posixpath that'll suit?

Comment: This approach adds a bug if the code ever runs on something Unix-ish. IOW it puts a time bomb in your code, triggered by "code gets ported" - which is exactly the situation where you have too many problems from deep down in the code already.

Comment: For anyone (like me) who was wondering, "Why the heck the double back-slashes!?" ("\\" instead of "\"), see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/501197/4561887

Comment: The correct **cross-platfom** method is to use `os.path.normpath()`. On Windows, it'll normalise the path to using backward slashes. If you have to have forward slashes, then you are probably dealing with URLs and not paths, so use URL-specific methods such as `urllib.parse.urljoin()` (requires actual URLs, not just a path).

Comment: Mixed slashes is *not actually a problem* as Windows is happy to process either, even if mixed.

Comment: I work in a wsl env, so I need double backslash at begin and then forward slashes. I do `local_path = '\\\\' + path.join(home_w, repo).split('\\\\')[1].replace('\\', '/')`. Result: `\\wsl$/debian/home../`

Answer (score 19):

try using abspath (using python 3)

```py
import os

a = 'c:/'
b = 'myFirstDirectory/'
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'


print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(a, b, c, d, e)))
```

OUTPUT:

```sh
c:\myFirstDirectory\mySecondDirectory\myThirdDirectory\myExecutable.exe

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `os.path.abspath()` calls `os.path.normpath()` first. You can achieve the same here, just call `os.path.normpath()`.

Comment: The problem remains as Windows cannot process the backslash correctly and think it is the escape char.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT based on comment:** `path = os.path.normpath(path)`

My previous answer lacks the capability of handling escape characters and thus **should not be used**:

- First, convert the path to an array of folders and file name.
- Second, glue them back together using the correct symbol.

  ```
  import os   
  path = 'c:\www\app\my/folder/file.php'
  # split the path to parts by either slash symbol:
  path = re.compile(r"[\/]").split(path)
  # join the path using the correct slash symbol:
  path = os.path.join(*path)
  ```

Comment: Note that if your string happen to use ` \ ` to escape spaces inside folders, this method will break. For example `"/usr/my\ files"` will translate to `"usr","my"," files"` instead of `"usr","my files"`

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Just use `os.path.normpath()`.

Answer (score 9):

If for any reason you need to provide the paths yourself and you have using anything above python 3.4 you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath

a = PurePosixPath('c:/')
b = PurePosixPath('myFirstDirectory/')
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'

print(a / b / c / d / e)

# Result
c:/myFirstDirectory/mySecondDirectory/myThirdDirectory/myExecutable.exe
```

I used this when I needed a user to provide the location of an assets directory and my code was looking up using windows path strings

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath
In [2]: USER_ASSETS_DIR = Path('/asset/dir') # user provides this form environment variable
In [3]: SPECIFIC_ASSET = PureWindowsPath('some\\asset')
In [4]: USER_ASSETS_DIR / SPECIFIC_ASSET

Out[4]: PosixPath('/asset/dir/some/asset')
```

Answer (score 1):

`os` adds slashes for you and makes sure not to duplicate slashes so omit them in your strings

```
import os

# Don't add your own slashes
a = 'C:'
b = 'myFirstDirectory' 
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'

print os.path.join(a, b, c, d, e)
C:\myFirstDirectory\mySecondDirectory\myThirdDirectory\myExecutable.exe
```

**Additional:**

I'm unsure as to why you have mixed slashes in your sys path (have you used a linux os to add some folders?) but try checking

`print os.path.isdir(os.path.join('C:','Users','nookie'))`.

If this is `True` then `os` works for your mixed slashes.

Either way, I would avoid hard-coding directory names into your program.  Your `sys.path` for loop is a safe way to pull out these directories.  You can then use some string methods, or regex to pick the desired folder.

Comment: os.path.isdir(os.path.join('C:','Users','nookie')) returns False.
I didn't use any Linux Os to add my folders, those came just from software installation!

Comment: What version of Python are you using, @ejrb? Because on mine, I don't get the first slash. (I see `C:myFirstDirectory\mySecondDirectory...`)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang, you're correct, their answer is wrong. To place the separator between the c: and myFirstDirectory you would need to add +os.sep to c: like so:
`os.path.join(a+os.sep, b, c, d, e)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
import re

a = 'c:/'
b = 'myFirstDirectory/'
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'

joined = os.path.join(a, b, c, d, e)
formatted = re.sub(r'/|\\', re.escape(os.sep), joined)
```

This is going to switch all your potentially mixed slashes into OS compliant ones.

I know it's an ancient topic but I couldn't resist. :)

Answer (score 1):

Postgres command client `psql` doesn't accept back slashes even on Windows:

```
>psql -U user -h 111.111.111.111 -d mydb
psql (12.2, server 12.5 . . .
. . .
mydb=> \i C:\my\path\myscript.sql
C:: Permission denied
```

So needed to fix it when executing from `Python 3.8.6`. Didn't want to resort to naive string replacement and used existing function:

```
script_path = Path(script_dir).resolve()
input_sql = f'\\i {script_path.joinpath("myscript.sql").as_posix()}\n'
```

But under the hood it has:

```
# ...\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\pathlib.py
    def as_posix(self):
        """Return the string representation of the path with forward (/)
        slashes."""
        f = self._flavour
        return str(self).replace(f.sep, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is fairly straightforward: `rstrip` all the paths from their slashes, regardless of quantity and correctness, add join those paths back using the correct separator.

```
import os

def join_path_regardless_of_separators(*paths):
    return os.path.sep.join(path.rstrip(r"\/") for path in paths)
 
a = 'c:/'
b = 'myFirstDirectory/'
c = 'mySecondDirectory'
d = 'myThirdDirectory\\\\\\/'
e = 'myExecutable.exe'
join_path_regardless_of_separators(a, b, c, d, e)
>>> 'c:\\myFirstDirectory\\mySecondDirectory\\myThirdDirectory\\myExecutable.exe'
```

Another way to use it, for the same result:

```
join_path_regardless_of_separators(*"""c:////\\\\
                                       myFirstDirectory/
                                       mySecondDirectory\\\\
                                       myThirdDirectory/////
                                       myExecutable.exe
                                    """.split())
```