# Resolving mixed slashes from sys.path and os.path.join

Tags: python, portability, arcpy, sys

I need to resolve a disparity between the separator that sys.path is providing, and the separator that os.path.join is using.

I mimicked this Esri method ([Techniques for sharing Python scripts](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00570000000p000000.htm)) to make my script portable. It is being used in Windows for now, but will eventually live on a Linux server; I need to let Python determine the appropriate slash.

What they suggest:

```
# Get the pathname to this script
scriptPath = sys.path[0]

# Get the pathname to the ToolShare folder
toolSharePath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)

# Now construct pathname to the ToolData folder
toolDataPath = os.path.join(toolSharePath, "ToolData")
print "ToolData folder: " + toolDataPath
```

But this outputs `ToolData folder: C:/gis\ToolData` -- and obviously the mixed slashes aren't going to work.

This Question ([mixed slashes with os.path.join on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333569/mixed-slashes-with-os-path-join-on-windows)) includes the basic approach to a solution:

> check your external input (the input you apparently do not control the format of) before putting it in `os.path.join`. This way you make sure that `os.path.join` does not make bad decisions based on possibly bad input

However, I'm unsure how to ensure that it will work cross-platform. If I use `.replace("/","\\")` on the `sys.path[0]` result, that's great for Windows, but isn't that going to cause the same mixed-slash problem once I transition to Unix?

Comment: Is `pathlib` an option? It's new in Python 3.4, and does not exist in Python 2.7.

Comment: I _think_ that I'm stuck with Python 2.7 because of a bunch of ArcPy functions that I use (and/or we only have 2.7 on the server).

Comment: Python can use forward slashes for Windows paths, so `sys.path[0].replace(r'\', '/')` might be your best be for cross-platform functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using [os.path.normpath()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normpath(r'c:\my/path\to/something.py')
'c:\\my\\path\\to\\something.py'
```

Also worth mentioning: the Windows path API doesn't care whether forward or back slashes are used. Usually it's the fault of program that doesn't handle the slashing properly. For example, in python:

```
with open(r'c:/path/to/my/file.py') as f:
    print f.read()
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

After [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and trying a lot of variations:

The `os.path.abspath` function can "clean" the slashes, so whichever direction slash `sys.path[0]` decides to use, the slashes will be replaced with the preferred separator.

```
scriptPath = sys.path[0]
toolDataPath = os.path.join(scriptPath, "ToolData")
```

Result: `C:/gis\ToolData`

```
scriptPath = sys.path[0]
toolSharePath = os.path.abspath(scriptPath)
# or, in one line: toolSharePath = os.path.abspath(sys.path[0])
toolDataPath = os.path.join(toolSharePath, "ToolData")
```

Result: `C:\gis\ToolData`

Comment: Do read that documentation carefully: *On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` ...*. Just call `os.path.normpath()` **directly** unless you also must make the path absolute.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `os.sep` character in Python, which stores your OS's preferred folder separating character. Perhaps you could perform a manual string `join` using that?

On Linux:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sep
'/'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep

Comment: The problem is that `os.sep` (in Windows, a backslash) doesn't match what `sys.path[0]` is using (a forward slash). It might do on Linux (haven't checked), but I would like it to operate cleanly in either platform.