# os.path.join - how to cope with absolute path

Tags: python

**Python 3.5.2**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I want to join them:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, STATIC_URL)
```

The result is '/static/'.

This is the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

We can read that "If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component."

In my case BASE_DIR in the debugger is '/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive/photoarchive'.

Well, this is an absolute path. Well, it eve was acquired via abspath function.

So, there first component - BASE_DIR - is an absolute path.

**Could you tell me why it is thrown away? 
And how to get '/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive/photoarchive/static'?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component." applies here: `STATIC_URL` is an absolute path because it starts with `/`, so `BASE_DIR` is dropped.

Drop the leading `/` else dirname thinks that `STATIC_URL` is absolute and keeps only that.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Comment: it's best to but not necessary to drop `/` from `static/` for [cross-platform compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333569/mixed-slashes-with-os-path-join-on-windows)

Comment: @loa_in_: yes. `os.path.normpath` would to that.