# In Python '\' is converted to '\\' even with rawstring or unicode settings

Tags: python, anaconda

I am relatively new to python and now have the following problem. Since recently whenever I generate or include a path in a code the \ is replaced by \. Like e.g. when using

```
os.join
```

or when using

```
r'mypat\myfiles\myfile.py'
```

or

```
u'mypat\myfiles\myfile.py'
```

A work around I found for myself so far was using '/' instead of '\' which did the job. But now I want to manually install a package and get the error

```
path wrong: C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda2\\pkgs\\...
```

I assume its something in the settings of either on my computer or the basic python settings. Its Window 7 and I tried German and English Language settings with the same result.

Comment: `print r'mypat\myfiles\myfile.py'` will output only 1 `'\'`. `'\\'` is internal string representation of `'\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

os.path.join() is multi-platform, if used on Windows, it will generate a windows path with \, for linux it will generate a linux path with "/

Linux :

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 08:03:08) 
[GCC 6.2.1 20160830] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("toto", "tutu")
'toto/tutu'
>>>
```

Windows :

```
λ python
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("toto", "tutu")
'toto\\tutu'
>>>
```

You should never use an hardcoded path in your code.
If your software is multi-platform, write path using linux style and then build it using os.path.join, it will be reformated

An other post which could interest you :
[mixed slashes with os.path.join on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333569/mixed-slashes-with-os-path-join-on-windows)

Comment: Thx. So If I want to use a code that uses os (and that I cannot change) on a windows machine, what can I do that its not toto\\tutu but toto\tutu?

Comment: toto\\tutu  is valid, toto\tutu is not valid , toto/tutu is valid. I would always use "/". (not sure to understand). If you really want have "\". i would just build my path, then replace "\\" or "/" with "\"

Comment: Thanks, I think the link and your comments made it clear to me. I thought  the \\ was the problem that the code couldn't find the path but I guess I have to search elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape them with an additional slash:

```
print('mypat\\myfiles\\myfile.py')
```

Comment: print(r'mypat\\myfiles\\myfile.py') generates 
mypat\\myfiles\\myfile.py

Comment: But why do you need to use the string representation, 'r' ?

Comment: @lapinokira: because print(r'mypat\myfiles\myfile.py') also generates mypat\\myfiles\\myfile.py.