# my function return /static/images%5Cstore%5Cteststore.1548589567.xlg.png

Tags: html, mongodb, flask

I'm making upload image function and I save image's id's within user model
and create a class method to find an image by join path with user info.
The problem is that I don't know what went wrong

I add str() to see the URL

```
STATIC_IMAGE_URL = 'image'

class Store(db.Document):
    ........
##this is class function ###
def store_imgsrc(self,size):
        if self.store_image:  #Locate img location and have size as parameter for using in different templates            
              return str(url_for('static', filename=os.path.join(STATIC_IMAGE_URL, 'store','%s.%s.%s.png' % (self.storename, self.store_image, size))))
```

HTML:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{store.store_imgsrc('xlg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

this will result in `"GET /static/images%5Cstore%5Cteststore.1548589567.xlg.png HTTP/1.1" 404`

My directory:

[image]

My code is very similar to this
https://github.com/fromzeroedu/flaskbook/blob/step-32/user/models.py

Comment: `%5C` is a backslash character.  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333569/mixed-slashes-with-os-path-join-on-windows)  might get you closer to a solution, possibly using `os.path.normpath`.  Probably needs some trial and error.

Comment: I tried ```os.path.normpath``` it seem to not working but I tried ```.replace('%5c','/') and it seem to work