# Invalid Argument Error from os.path.join()

Tags: python, logging, os.path

I am trying to run a project from GitHub but logging is proving to be difficult. I am running the code on Windows 10, but the OS.Path.Join() keeps adding a forward-slash to my log folder and thus I keep getting an error.

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 515, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: log/2022-01-06 13:56:12_BRVOZQinit.cp; Invalid argument
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16333785/9236660

Comment: First, I thank you for your response! Now, I've checked many questions on this topic and I'd already noticed people were having an issue regarding manually placed slashes. I checked the application and it doesn't contain any manually placed slashes. I'll double check again and if there is anything, I'll let you know!