# get unix style path join in python

Tags: python, url, routes, path, wsgi

While making a **wsgi app** I am in need of **joining route names** like */apple*,  *apple/buy* etc.

```
    import os
    path = os.path.join("/apple/", "/buy")
    print("route path:", path)
```

Now the problem is it **works fine in *nix** systems but on **dos ones the ouput could become**:

```
    route path: apple\buy
```

cuz what is wanted was unix style paths like - `apple/buy`

is their a way that I can always get unix style paths? should I use something other than os module?

Comment: You only need the output to print/show some string? If that's the case, does `.replace("\\", "/")` after the path definition solve the problem? ([Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776536/3281097))

Comment: @aaossa well looks all right but what would happen when someone does

`os.path.join("this/", "/is/", "a url/").replace("\\, "/")`

i guess it would still work. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4):

`os.path` is a alias to `posixpath` or `ntpath`. You can import one of those modules directly to get the path rules you want. So, `import posixpath` and use functions like `posixpath.join`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.__name__
'posixpath'
>>> import posixpath
>>> posixpath.join is os.path.join
True
>>>
```

You could

```
import os
import posixpath
os.path = posixpath
```

But that can be a bad choice because it would also affect any code that wants to work with local platform paths. Its usually best to use `posixpath` directly as needed.

Comment: Additionally, you could import `posixpath.join` directly with an alias: `from posixpath import join as posixjoin`

Comment: @tdelaney I guess posixpath is ideal for weburls then. I am not using it for local platform paths. infact I am intending to use it in a url router module. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`os.path` is for path operations on the current operating system.
Use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to join URL paths.

Comment: thats by far the best answer. thanks