# Flask SQLAlchemy sqlite database uri on Windows with app.instance_path

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple flask app I am developing and I switch between a Windows PC and Linux PC for development. I was originally trying to use `os.path.join` and `os.path.abspath` to get the path for my database using `app.instance_path` but I could not get back slashes to escape by using that method on Windows and was getting `unable to open database` errors, so I have changed the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to be relative by using `sqlite:///../instance/test.db`. This works in both Windows and Linux, but it seems like the proper way to do things would be to use the `app.instance_path` variable which is built into Flask.

For example using: `db_path = 'sqlite:////' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'test.db'))`

```
# Windows:
print(db_path)
sqlite:////C:\Users\user\test-app\instance\test.db

# Linux:
print(db_path)
sqlite://///home/user/test-app/instance/test.db
```

On Windows I get an `unable to open database` error. I'm assuming because the back slashes `\` are not escaped.
On Linux it works great.

Using: `db_path = 'sqlite:////' + os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'test.db'))`
Yields the same results as above

I also read from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333569/mixed-slashes-with-os-path-join-on-windows) that's it's not good practice to use a string literal, so I haven't attempted that.

What would be the most proper way to set the DATABASE_URI? Should I just stick with the relative path `../instance/test.db` or try to use the `os.path`/`app.instance_path` methods? If I should use the `app.instance_path` method, what is the proper way to get the correct paths on both Windows and Linux?

Thanks!